# Preparing data for Plotly in R

Tags: r, postgresql, dbplyr

I am able to create datatables, pivots, maps etc. but, cannot for the life of me create a dataset usable in Plotly for R.

In this example I keep getting and error in the last element ending with 'object 'prem_council' not found

My code is:

```
#### DATA ##
lic1 <- tbl(con, "ca_licenses") %>% 
  select(type,license,lic_app,status,master,prem_city_ps,class_parent,prem_council,prem_neighborhood) %>%
    filter(prem_city_ps == "LOS ANGELES", lic_app == "LIC", status == "ACTIVE", master == "Y") %>%
      collect()

lic2 <- tbl_df(lic1) 

lic3 <- as_tibble(cbind(nms = names(lic2), t(lic2)))

plot_ly(lic3, x = prem_council, y = type, type = "bar")
```

I removed my comments so I don't appear as a complete donk. My question is what exactly are the steps for taking a typical dataset of row/column data and preparing it to create Plotly charts? My steps are:

lic1 <- collecting/filtering/selecting the data from a postgres table (works great),
lic2 <- creating a dataframe
lic3 <- creating a tibble by transposing data and where first col is now the names (nms) column 
And lastly creating the chart.

[image: Image illustrates the output from lic3]

I have used rm(list=ls()) to flush the memory as I've tried many different things.

Loaded libraries include RPostgreSQL, DBI, dbplyr, dplyr, plotly

Any insight would be appreciated! New to R and can't wait to get this down. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to fix an error or is this code already working?

Comment: I'm trying to fix the error. This is the complete message: Error in plot_ly(lic3, x = prem_council, y = type, type = "bar") : 
  object 'prem_council' not found

Answer (score 0):

When you write `prem_council`, R is looking for that object in the workspace, not in the tibble you have created, therefore it cannot find it. Try this instead

```
plot_ly(lic3, x = ~prem_council, y = ~type, type = "bar")
```

Comment: Thanks Javad. I tried that as well and when I tried just not, I get this error: 'Error in eval(expr, data, expr_env) : object 'prem_council' not found'.

Comment: It is hard to say because I don't see the data. When you examine lic3, does it have the perm_council field?